# Why does using the 'search' function in the YouTube Data API use up so much of my quota?

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

I've been trying to develop an application that returns the first video result for a keyword (as well as getting its content details). This is done multiple times in a session (let's say, like 30 times). If all I'm doing is reading data from 1 result each time (from the "Calculating quota usage" section of [their docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)), then why is it that I use up all 10,000 of my daily units with a few test runs of my application?

Here's my specific code:

```
private class GetVideoDuration extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String sURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + params[0] + "&part=contentDetails&key=" + API_KEY;
            String var = null;

            try {
                // Connect to the URL using java's native library
                URL url = new URL(sURL);
                URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
                request.connect();

                // Convert to a JSON object to print data
                JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
                JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
                Log.d("rootJSON", root.toString());
                Log.d("urlJSON", url.toString());
                JsonObject video = null;
                try {
                    video = root.getAsJsonObject().get("items").getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("contentDetails").getAsJsonObject();
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Chief", "It looks like we've exceeded our quota for the day :(");
                }
                var = video.get("duration").getAsString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // contDets = contentDetails
                Log.d("Error parsing contDets", e.getMessage());
                ERROR_STATE = true;
            }

            return var;
        }
    }
```

I'm aware of the option to apply for a higher quota, but it just seems like something's wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.